# backbone events are not triggered by the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am working with Backbone and Jquery. I have a button inside a template and for some reason that button does not trigger any `click` events. I've tried all the suggested solutions on `stackoverflow` but none of them worked for me. Below is the code Im working with - I've made it as short as possible.

Any ideas why the `YES` button does not work?

### EditView.html

```
<section id="EditView">
    <button id="button-yes">YES</button>
</section>
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
    <header id="header"></header>

    <div id="content"><div id="content-inner"></div></div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>

     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">      </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myapp =  myapp || {};

 myapp.EditView = Backbone.View.extend({

events: {
    'click #button-yes': 'buttonClickHandler'
 },

initialize: function () {
    this.render();
},

render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template());                                  

    return this;    // support chaining
},

buttonClickHandler : function(event){
    alert( $(event.currentTarget).text() );
    return false;
}

 });


     myapp.utils = {

loadTemplates: function(views, callback) {

    var deferreds = [];

    $.each(views, function(index, view) {
        if (myapp[view]) {
            deferreds.push($.get(view + '.html', function(data) {
                myapp[view].prototype.template = _.template(data);
            }));
        } else {
            console.log(view + " not found");
        }
    });

    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
}
 };


    myapp.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
    "": "add"
        },

initialize: function() {
    this.add;
},

add: function() {
    if (!this.editView) {
        this.editView = new myapp.EditView({el: $("#content-inner")});
    };
    $('#content').html(this.editView.el);
}
 });

myapp.utils.loadTemplates([ 'EditView'], function() {
myapp.router = new myapp.AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
});


 </script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The basic view structure works (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8c9tgoyu/). Are you sure that your template is what you expect it to be? Are you sure that your template loader is doing the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you're having a problem, seems to be some race condition where the element doesn't exist when backbone attempts to bind the event to it.  It's an interesting case.  Anyway, you can solve it for now by adding

```
myapp.router.editView.delegateEvents();
```

after Backbone.history.start();